# How to create a file using command-line interface (CLI) in a Raspberry Pi terminal?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, terminal, file

How can I *create* an empty **file** using a command line interface in a Terminal application of a Raspberry Pi instead of using the File Manager?

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To create a **file** using command-line interface (CLI) in a Raspberry Pi terminal use ***touch*** command as illustrated below:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ touch README.rst
```

It could be any kind of file, such as .txt or .html